# Need some help making an Indexed view with 2 COUNT_BIG's

Tags: sql, t-sql, subquery, indexed-view

Ok, I'm trying to make an indexed view that is against a simple table that stores the results of what people think is good/bad for a post. This is the results of a thumbs up / thumbs down, voting on posts.

So here's my pseduo fake table :-

```
HelpfulPostId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
PostId INT NOT NULL,
IsHelpful BIT NOT NULL,
UserId INT NOT NULL
```

So a user can only have one vote per post. It's either a 1 (helpful) or 0 (unhelpful) <-- not sure of a better way to handle that, if there is a better way.

Ok.
What i'm trying to do is get a view that looks like the following.

<strike>HelpfulPostId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,</strike>

```
PostId INT NOT NULL,
IsHelpfulCount COUNT_BIG (WHERE IsHelpful = 1)
IsNotHelpfulCount COUNT_BIG (WHERE IsHelpful = 0)
```

And finally, i'll need to make it schemabindable so i can add an index on the PK and then an index on the PostId.

I have no idea about the sql to make the view. Any suggestions?

Cheers :)

Comment: how can you possibly count_big when the max rows is limited by an int primary key?

Comment: I did that because indexed views only like COUNT_BIG when you try and do a COUNT field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thoughts:

- You can't use COUNT(*) in an indexed view
- You can't aggregate bit fields

There are other [limitations of indexed views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx)

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Example
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
    PostId,
    SUM(CAST(IsHelpful AS bigint)) AS IsHelpfulCount,
    SUM(CAST(1-IsHelpful AS bigint)) AS IsNotHelpfulCount,
    COUNT_BIG(*) AS Dummy   --Used to satisfy requirement
FROM
    dbo.bob
GROUP BY
    PostId
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IXC_Test ON dbo.Example (PostId)
GO
```

Edit: 
Removed the Identity field, which was accidently added to the original question/post.

Edit 2 (gbn):
I forgot that any aggregate in an indexed view *also* needs a COUNT_BIG(*). So, simply add one as a dummy column. I've tested this.

> If the view definition uses an
>   aggregate function, the SELECT list
>   must also include COUNT_BIG (*).

Comment: Um .. that's not going to work :( How does it know what the count of IsHelpfulCount is?? that's what i need to define, in this view :( Can that be a subquery?

Comment: With a little tweaking, it's now good. I had to drop the Indentity field (i accidenly posted that as a result .. which is impossible when i'm doing aggregations :P). I checked against a quick select with 2x subqueries (doing a count) and it's all good :) I'm lucky i'm using 1&0.. so the SUM would work :)

Comment: :( when I try to index this view, it doesn't work. Saying i need a COUNT_BIG(*) ???

Comment: .. but it now works (I can add a unique clustered index) when i add the following, to the select statement.. => COUNT_BIG(*) AS TotalCount

Comment: cheers. Confirmed also. Works great :) cheers mate for following through with this.